# Receiving "wrong type argument: commandp..." when hacking around emacs evil mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I am trying to override some of the default keymaps of emacs evil mode. What I have done is this:

```lisp
(evil-define-key 'visual 'global
  "<" (lambda ()
    (evil-shift-left)
    (evil-visual-restore))
  ">" (lambda ()
    (evil-shift-right)
    (evil-visual-restore)))
```

And I got this error message: `Wrong type argument: commandp, (lambda nil (evil-shift-left) (evil-visual-restore))` when I press `>`, when the expected behavior was shifting the selected text right and restore visual mode.

Since I am only 2 days into trying to learn emacs, I am pretty confused what I have done wrong here.

Comment: Why? Because it is not a command. ||| Solution: Add `(interactive)` right after `(lambda ()`. ||| Your first step should be to learn some **basic** ELisp knowledge, otherwise you'll waste your time. In the words of *Confucius*: "*To think without learning is perilous.*"

Comment: See <https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Interactive.html>. (This is an excellent book to get started with ELisp.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank the great advice by @shynur, and I really do agree now that learning the basic of elisp is crucial before starting to hack emacs. Still, I figured out how to solve my problem and it is not quite as simple as adding `interactive`. My solution goes like this:

```lisp
(evil-define-key 'visual 'global
  (kbd "<") (lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (call-interactively 'evil-shift-left)
        (evil-normal-state)
        (evil-visual-restore))
  (kbd ">") (lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (call-interactively 'evil-shift-right)
        (evil-normal-state)
        (evil-visual-restore)))
```

Referred also to https://superuser.com/questions/684540/evil-mode-evil-shift-left-loses-selection

Comment: FYI: You can accept your own answer.

Comment: @Drew Intended to but was told I could only do that in two days time